# Smooth (almost) everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f|_{\mathbb R\setminus S}$ is $C^\infty$ for a finite set $S$. 
Is $f$ differentiable on the whole $\mathbb R$? Is it $C^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ but is not differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Not even $C^{\infty}$.